# Pagination not working with django-tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I don't get any pagination at all, it is supposed to be automatic.
I am using django_mail_admin for the models

Table code

```
class IncomingTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = IncomingEmail
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields = ("id", "subject",)
```

View code, there seems to be some duplication of models

```
class IncomingMail(SingleTableView):
    table_class = IncomingTable
    queryset = IncomingEmail.objects.all().order_by("-id")
    template_name = "incoming.html"
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `paginate_by` or `per_page` in the metaclass if that works?